# Are there any good Java cross platform SIP / VOIP Development Kits?

Tags: java, sdk, voip, sip

Are there any good Java cross platform SIP / VOIP dev kits that you have personally used? I've found one or two that seem like they could be worthwhile pursuing, but I'm still not 100% sold on them.

http://www.voipdevelopmentkit.com/

That seems to be the leader at the moment. However, it doesn't look like they are developing still. I've had a few emails with them and the answers provided were great.

I have a Java application that requires an inbuilt SIP endpoint. I'd like to avoid wrapping native libraries if possible, as this application needs to run on Windows, Mac OS X, and potentially Linux systems.

Something with third party call control (3pcc) would instantly top the list, but it's not a 100% requirement as I figure I can implement that myself without too much worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [peers](http://peers.sourceforge.net/), this is a java sip client I developed. It is typically used to add telephony feature in an already existing application. It is 100% pure java and cross platform (works on windows, linux and mac).

Comment: The documentation there is absolutely fantastic! Though I'm no longer in the market for SIP software, it looks promising. I'll still probably end up reading all the docs anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check JAIN SIP it is the reference implementation of JSR 32, free and public domain and very active https://jsip.java.net/

Comment: It took awhile, but finally an answer! Thanks a lot, I'll take a closer look at it.